# Read Laravel session from native PHP

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I have Laravel 4 app on my main domain and I have native PHP app on subdomain, but I need them to share session.

I have tried doing this in Laravel 4 `app/config/session.php`:

```
'driver' => 'cookie', // i have also tried native

'cookie' => 'puskice_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => '.mysite.com'
```

So when I try doing `native` and go to native PHP with `var_dump($_SESSION);` I get

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

When I switch to `cookie` I can do `var_dump($_COOKIE['laravel_session']);` but I get encrypted session.

Is there any way of doing this? I should mention also that I have another subdomain with another Laravel 4 app, and it works between Laravel 4 apps, but not with native.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel Cookie value isn't actually encrypted, simply base64 encoded, so (for example) a session value of

```
eyJpdiI6Ik5adGdiU1MxT1cybEprbjFvZzg1OCtOMnRabm44Q0o3NGd5SjJVbUF3THM9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJFZ2hpNENIenhoWktwMjhkRTVaKzBKMjFPT1wvNGs2VENtQTB0Z1l2SWtBb1U1UFdsRmdRNFZmVjdGc3NkbFIyNHNSUnk4NjIreDRNS0tcL0dcL2dyTnJUZz09IiwibWFjIjoiYjc5N2U5YzM0ODQyYTY4YzkxNDgzNzM1OWZlZWQ4ODk3NjA3N2YxNmExMTY2ZTRjNDc2MGMzNzg2ZjhhMmZkYSJ9
```

can be base64 decoded to give

```
{"iv":"NZtgbSS1OW2lJkn1og858+N2tZnn8CJ74gyJ2UmAwLs=","value":"Eghi4CHzxhZKp28dE5Z+0J21OO\/4k6TCmA0tgYvIkAoU5PWlFgQ4VfV7FssdlR24sRRy862+x4MKK\/G\/grNrTg==","mac":"b797e9c34842a68c914837359feed88976077f16a1166e4c4760c3786f8a2fda"}
```

That may be of some help to you

Comment: Value in my cookie is something like `de2a711c6323bd342ef6207a76b95bbd`. When that goes to `base64decode` it comes out as nothing

Comment: `de2a711c6323bd342ef6207a76b95bbd` would not be a standard laravel session cookie value.... that looks more like a standard PHP (md5 hash) session cookie value